# Windows Phone 7 How to Make An App Do Something After Installation

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight

How to make an app do something after it is installed from the MarketPlace?

Well, if it is possible at all, that is.

Comment: Do you mean the first time the user runs the app or directly afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible to have the app do something after an install in wp7.

You could have it do something on first run of the app with custom code.  Basically cache an 'already been run' value into isolated storage.